# Can I say "sufficient enough" here?

Tags: grammar

> Your money is not **sufficient enough** to buy my heart. (self-made)

Is it redundant or simply incorrect  to use *sufficient* and *enough* together?  Or is it acceptable?

Comment: It *is* redundant. *Good enough* or *bad enough* use enough to qualify but *sufficient* cannot use *enough* the same way because it's a synonym. Of course, in a literary way, or for pun, you can always do :)

Comment: I've got ***sufficient*** money; but is it ***enough***?.

Comment: Salesman: "You can buy this car only if you have sufficient money."  Man, opening his briefcase: "Is this sufficient enough?"

Answer (score 4):

Using *sufficient* or *enough* alone is correct. Using both is incorrect.

Comment: So sufficient is enough or enough is sufficient in this sentence :)

Comment: @anotherdave I'd be inclined to add "enough is enough" but that means something else.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the comments of @Kris and and @Jasper Loy, with which I concur, you should use the word 'insufficient', so that it reads:

> Your money is insufficient to buy my heart.